# feedparser cannot get namespace values

Tags: python, xml, feedparser

hi i am trying to find the best way to extract values from a string returned from feedparser, basically its returning the following, i can of course do a regex match but im sure there is a better way.

xml looks like this:-

```
<description>
   Size: 2247 MB People: 5,951 Hash: 9df49c5de014df3b5f202f51dc849b37cf82a3ad
</description>
```

result from feedparser looks like this:-

```
 Size: 2247 MB People: 5,951 Hash: 9df49c5de014df3b5f202f51dc849b37cf82a3ad
```

so basically i want Size, People, and Hash values e.g.

```
2247
5,951
9df49c5de014df3b5f202f51dc849b37cf82a3ad
```

ive read up as much as i can about doing this and im not 100% sure on my teminology but i think this is related to namespace?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

s = "Size: 2247 MB People: 5,951 Hash: 9df49c5de014df3b5f202f51dc849b37cf82a3ad"
arr = re.split('Size: |People: |Hash: ', s)
arr = [x.strip() for x in arr][1:]
print arr
```

Output `['2247 MB', '5,951', '9df49c5de014df3b5f202f51dc849b37cf82a3ad']`

Comment: thanks for the post, so im assuming from this there is no way i can get to the values using feedparser without doing some sort of string manipulation using regex?

Comment: I don't think so, description it's not formated following any standard I know